# Results not correctly sorted when calling stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We have a stored procedure that uses a parameter and a CASE in ORDER BY to sort the results by different columns. If we execute the stored procedure from SSMS, the records are always sorted according to the parameter no matter which version of SQL Server we use (2005 or 2008). If we call it from the app with the exact same parameter values, it only does the ordering correctly with SQL Server 2005. I stepped through the SQLDataReader and it's getting the records in the wrong order with 2008.

I tried in .NET 2.0 as well to be sure it didn't have something to do with the .NET framework version being 4.0 and I got the same results.

The only difference between these servers that I'm aware of, besides SQL Server version, is the server with SQL 2008 is a multi-processor.

What could be the cause for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the .NET code calling your stored proc?  It could be the issue is there.

Comment: Also can we see the stored procedure? It isn't using `SELECT TOP <some big number> ... ORDER BY ...` in a CTE is it?

Comment: It would be insanely helpful if we could see the sorting T-SQL in the proc as well as the .NET code you are calling the SQL Proc from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that your `CASE` statement is checking for `NULL` values in the parameter. Sending .NET `NULL` values may not play nice with SQL `NULL` values using default settings.

For example, if your parameter is a string, and you're using the integrated `SQLDataProvider` then there is a setting which automatically replaces `NULL` strings with **blank** strings. 
I would verify that your .NET is actually sending the parameter you think it is by having the sproc `SELECT` your parameter.

If you are, in fact, depending on a `NULL` parameter, I would handle the validation in your .NET and then just not send the parameter to the sproc. This is a pretty fool-proof way to make sure the parameter is actually `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I saw this kind of strange errors when the database is a SQL Server 2005 and running under 2008.

Make sure the compatibility level matches the server version.

A picture worth a 1000 words:

[image]

In this case, the database is not in the recommended compatibility level.

**CAUTION!!! Once you change the compatibility level, you might not be able to undo it, so please make a backup!!!**

**CAUTION!!! Once you change the compatibility level, you might not be able to undo it, so please make a backup!!!**

**CAUTION!!! Once you change the compatibility level, you might not be able to undo it, so please make a backup!!!**

Comment: @Luis Out of curiosity, did this help?